# How to change ZedGraph Y axis order?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I have a `ZedGraph` control with multiple Y axis, and I want to allow the user to change the order in which the Y axis are displayed.

Unfortunately there is no `Move` method on the `YAxisList` object of the `GraphPane`, like it exists on the `CurveList`.

The indexers on the `YAxisList` are readonly. I can not use [the good old swap snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094239/swap-two-items-in-listt) to swap axis in the list.

How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a extension method inspired by the `Move` method of the `CurveList`.

The trap is that the Y Axis Indexes of existing curves needs to be updated accordingly.

```
public static int Move(this YAxisList list, GraphPane pane, int index, int relativePos)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= list.Count)
        return -1;

    var axis = list[index];
    list.RemoveAt(index);

    var newIndex = index + relativePos;

    if (newIndex < 0)
        newIndex = 0;
    if (newIndex > list.Count)
        newIndex = list.Count;

    list.Insert(newIndex, axis);

    foreach (var curve in pane.CurveList)
        if (curve.YAxisIndex == newIndex)
            curve.YAxisIndex = index;
        else if (curve.YAxisIndex == index)
            curve.YAxisIndex = newIndex;

    return newIndex;
}
```