# How to change the index of an array element in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a array which contains 7 elements and i need to move 5 and 6 index elements to 1 and 2 position  and vice versa

say for example

```
 ItemParameter[] parameters = {a,b,c,d,f,g,h};
```

and i need

```
 {a,g,h,d,f,b,c}
```

Comment: This is oddly specific. Is this a specific example of a more general case that you want to solve? Also the lack of `e` in the example is making me twitch slightly. ;) As is the duplicated `a` in the expected output...

Comment: Your example doesn't match your description.  You go from a 7-element array to an 8-element array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swap two items in List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094239/swap-two-items-in-listt)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using an **extension** method defined as:

```
public static void Switch<T>(this IList<T> array, int index1, int index2)
{
    var aux = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = aux;
}
```

use simply as:

```
ItemParameter[] arr = {a,b,c,d,f,g,h};
arr.Switch(2, 6);
arr.Switch(1, 5);
```

Comment: Now it's basically [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2094316/284240) but  ++ anyway

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, it seems like it is :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ItemParameter[] arr = {a,b,c,d,f,g,h};

// swap elements of index 1 and 5
var tmp = arr[1];
arr[1] = arr[5];
arr[5] = tmp;

// swap elements of index 2 and 6
tmp = arr[2];
arr[2] = arr[6];
arr[6] = tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to randomize (shuffle) the array content, you can use the method below to shuffle the array content after you initialize the array.

It can be used like so:

```
ItemParameter[] arr = {a,b,c,d,f,g,h};
ShuffleArr(arr);
```

The method:

```
public static void ShuffleArr<T>(T[] arr)
{  
    Random rng = new Random();  
    int n = arr.Length;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = arr[k];  
        arr[k] = arr[n];  
        arr[n] = value;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
    ItemParameter[] parameters = {a,b,c,d,f,g,h};
    ItemParameter tmp = new ItemParameter();
    tmp = parameters[5];
    parameters[5] = parameters[0];
    parameters[0] = tmp;
    tmp = parameters[6];
    parameters[6] = parameters[1];
    parameters[1] = tmp;
```

Comment: there not exists anything on parameteres[7] , also last line should be parameters[1]=tmp