# Yield return in recursion doesn't return value even after ".ToList()" call

Tags: c#, recursion, permutation, yield

When I make a call to generation permutations, 2nd `GeneratePermutations(list, startCount, permutationCount)` do yield return 6 times (`yield return permutationList;`). But for some reason, `result` in the first `GetPermutations` doesn't contain anything even though I did called `.ToList()` on the result.

Does this have anything to do recursion?

`Test.cs`

```
IEnumerable<int[]> actual = _sut.GetPermutations(3).ToList();
```

`Perm.cs`

```
public class Perm
{
    public IEnumerable<int[]> GetPermutations(int permutationCount)
    {
        int[] permutationList = Enumerable.Range(1, permutationCount).ToArray();
        IEnumerable<int[]> result = GeneratePermutations(permutationList, 0, permutationCount - 1).ToList();

        // Doesn't contain any value!
        return result;
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/756083/4035
    private IEnumerable<int[]> GeneratePermutations(int[] permutationList, int startCount, int permutationCount)
    {
        if (startCount == permutationCount)
        {
            // Does return 6 times here.
            yield return permutationList;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = startCount; i <= permutationCount; i++)
            {
                Swap(ref permutationList, startCount, i);
                GeneratePermutations(permutationList, startCount + 1, permutationCount).ToList();
                Swap(ref permutationList, startCount, i);
            }

        }
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/2094316/4035
    public static void Swap(ref int[] list, int index1, int index2)
    {
        int tmp = list[index1];
        list[index1] = list[index2];
        list[index2] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Independently from your issue: Get your data type quirkiness sorted in `GetPermutations()`. You don't need `List<int[]>`: throw the casting away.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst: I just changed the type as suggested just in case both in the source and in my code.

Comment: Please note that `ref` is no needed in the `Swap` method.

Comment: @YacoubMassad True, it's not set to null or resized / reinitialized therefore ref can bo omitted.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes. I removed `ref` and it works fine as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is, that you never return the results of your recursive calls and that you work with the same array all the time. This would be the fastest fix for your code (not the best, but I'm sure you'll figure it out from here):

```
IEnumerable<int[]> perms = GeneratePermutations(
    new List<int>(permutationList).ToArray(), 
    startCount + 1, permutationCount);

foreach(int[] perm in perms)
    yield return perm;
```

btw: you can make the entire class static and generic

[Proof on dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ntov7J)

Comment: yes, indeed the problem was that I was working on the same `permutationList` and creating a copy each time fixed the issue. Thanks